# Mapping identifiers transitively

Tags: r, join, merge, dataset

I have three sets of identifiers: "x", "y", and "z". I also have two, 2-column data frames that each map one set of identifiers to another set of identifiers.

```
x2y = data.frame( x = c("A","A","B","B","C","D","E","F"),
                  y = c(1,2,1,2,3,4,4,5) )
y2z = data.frame( y = c(1,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,5),
                  z = c(1,2,3,3,6,7,6,7,8) )
```

This can be visualized in the figure below. Note that each arrow corresponds to one row in a data frame.

[image]

**Question:**
How do I use these two mappings (two data frames) to make a mapping 
from `x` to `z` (displayed on the right of the figure above). I
think of it as a "transitive mapping": `x to y` and `y to z` gives `x to z`.
The data frame that I would like is...

```
x2z = data.frame( x = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","D","D","E","E","F","F","F"),
                  z = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,3,6,7,6,7,6,7,8) )
```

**Notes:** My data frames are usually ~50,000 rows, so efficient code is very important. When I've solved this problem with loops, it took several minutes to run.
My only requirement is that the code be in R.

Comment: Your graphic looks spiffy. How did you make it?

Comment: It's manually drawn with Adobe Illustrator. I had considered using something like Rgraphviz, but it wasn't worth the time for this small, single-use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to merge:

```
merge(x2y, y2z)[c('x','z')]
##    x z
## 1  A 1
## 2  A 2
## 3  B 1
## 4  B 2
## 5  A 3
## 6  B 3
## 7  C 3
## 8  D 6
## 9  D 7
## 10 E 6
## 11 E 7
## 12 F 6
## 13 F 7
## 14 F 8
```

It helps here that the names agree where necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I always enjoy when 28 characters solves my 1,655-character plus figure question. It works great.